# Getting errors and need suggestions to automate

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Conn2SQL()

    Dim cnn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim iCols As Integer

    Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
      cnn1.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};server=MyDBServer;uid=MyuserID;pwd=mypassword;database=MyDB"
      cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 30
      cnn1.Open

    SQry = "use MyDB select * from TableName"

    mrs.Open SQry, cnn1

    For iCols = 0 To mrs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("SavedConfig").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = mrs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next

    SavedConfig.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs

    mrs.Close
    cnn1.Close

End Sub
```

I have named my worksheet as SavedConfig instead of Sheet1 but getting error 424 object required. Also, rather than hard coding the query above can we make it to pick the query from another worksheet of the excel instead.

---

How to make the connection string more dynamic instead of hard coding it rather picking up the values from cells of the excel worksheet.

```
cnn1.ConnectionString = "driver={SQLServer};server=MyDBServer;uid=MyuserID;pwd=mypassword;database=MyDB"
```

Comment: Need urgent help please

Comment: Your worksheet's `CodeName` is "SavedConfig" ?  Does it work if you use `Worksheets("SavedConfig")` instead?

Comment: `SQry = Worksheets("Queries").Range("A2").Value`

Comment: @Tim Williams instead of using typical worksheet name as Sheet1 I have used SavedConfig. The idea is to copy the data from SQL server and store it in a worksheet named SavedConfig

Comment: There are two "names" - the tab name, and the codename.  Which one did you set?  Both?

Comment: It is the tab name @TimWilliams

Comment: Then why not use `Worksheets("SavedConfig")` as you do inside the loop? Where exactly is the error?

Comment: It says object required 424 error. @TimWilliams

Comment: @TimWilliams can you help

Comment: You never defined `SavedConfig` as a worksheet. Replace `SavedConfig.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs` with `Worksheets("SavedConfig").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs`

Comment: I'm *trying* to help but you're ignoring my question about which line has the error.

Comment: How to make the connection string more dynamic instead of hard coding it rather picking up the values from cells of the excel worksheet.

cnn1.ConnectionString = "driver={SQLServer};server=MyDBServer;uid=MyuserID;pwd=mypassword;database=MyDB"

Comment: How to make the connection string more dynamic instead of hard coding it rather picking up the values from cells of the excel worksheet. cnn1.ConnectionString = "driver={SQLServer};server=MyDBServer;uid=MyuserID;pwd=mypassword;database=MyDB"

Comment: How to add the code for showing the Last run start time and date and last run end time and date of the query which is being executed, getting tabulated automatically in the excel cells.